# WPF: Binding the items in a "sub-list" of a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid in WPF that I bind to my ObservableCollection List, then I create the Columns for properties that I want, like the following ones:

```
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long Cod { get; set; }
    public long ProductRef{ get; set; }

    public List<SubProduct> ListSpecs {get; set;}
```

The problem is, that collection has a list of sub-products and I need to create a new column for at least the first Item of that list. The Datagrid would be like the following:

```
|Name|Date|Cod|ProductRef|ListSpecs[0]|ListSpecs[1]|
```

How can that be achieved? I don't want to add more properties to bind the items of that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work. For example for your first item of the subcollection.
Or you could try out binding the entire subcollection to a combobox?

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="item" Binding="{Binding Name}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="subitems" Binding="{Binding ListSpecs[0]}"  />  // first item of subcollection
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="subitems" Binding="{Binding ListSpecs[1]}"  /> // second item of sub collection
        </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>
```